# Recursively GET from IP white listed S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line

I have a bucket with an IP white listed policy, I would like to be able to s3 cp, or recursively wget everything in a "sub-folder" of that bucket. Is there a way to do this? The wget works fine on a single file.

What I've tried:

1. AWS cp with no profile set relying on the IP white list, this fails with a 403.
2. A recursive wget, this fails with a 403.
3. A wget with a wildcard, this is not actually a thing in HTTP.

IP white listing is very useful, it would be nice to get whole "folders" instead of just individual objects.

Comment: The problem is that wget "recursive" relies on behavior that is common for many web servers but not part of S3 -- auto-generated index documents that can be crawled.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yea I figured that was the behavior, since S3 goes off of keys and doesn't have true directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in my case the issue was that we were white listing on GET but not LIST, if anyone else runs into this problem make sure you have both.

The AWS CLI in order to do a recursive GET first "quietly" lists the objects in the bucket. That's why were able to wget a single item but not GET multiples through S3.

The second thing I was running into was that you need valid credentials (so not an empty string etc) as @john-rotenstein points out in his comment to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to copy the files, either:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://bucket/path/* localdir
```

or

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/path/ localdir
```

This would require a set of AWS credentials because API calls are authenticated while your `wget` method appears to be unauthenticated. If the bucket policy is granting public access (List and Get) on the bucket, then the credentials do not actually need additional permissions.

Comment: I have added IP white listing to the bucket policy, which is why the wget succeeds, it is not publicly readable.

Comment: That's good. The AWS CLI request will therefore work from the IP address too. However, it will still need a set of credentials to operate.

Comment: That helped, the other part of the problem was the inability to list objects. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: If you mean that you are unable to run the `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname` command, then add `ListBucket` permissions to the Bucket Policy.